# Google Fonts giving: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: fonts, google-font-api

I'm trying to use a google font 'Oswald'.  When i embed it into my page in the [recommended way](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Oswald):

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Chrome throws the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://<<redacted>>' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is this just a mistake on google's part or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use ' to delimit argument values in HTML tags. It's not standard, and it's simply wrong.

Comment: @Qualcuno uh, thanks, but that was copied directly from the Google Fonts page. https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Oswald

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out it was a conflict with [prefixfree](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/pull/39)

Solution was to add "data-noprefix" to the link tag, like so:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' data-noprefix>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have had issues with // in the past in some browsers.  If the site does not have an SSL certificate, i don't see why this matters.

Comment: no it does not but it means you can't install an SSL without it causing an notification

Comment: I added the 'data-noprefix' but am still getting the error.