# CORS error on Chrome with Google Fonts

Tags: django, google-chrome, cors

With a recent upgrade of Chrome, I get the following error:

> *Font from origin 'http://storage.googleapis.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.*

when calling the following from my html template in Django:

```
<link title="fonts" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I realise this is a CORS issue (it works perfectly on Safari which does not enforce CORS on fonts) so have installed django-cors-headers, and allowed all hosts but the error persists.  This is my only CORS issue and rather frustrating as the app has worked perfectly on Safari and Chrome (the only browsers that we use) for months!

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: It's not obvious to us what might be on your page that would affect your `<link>` that you think `django-cors-headers` might help. Could your clarify? For instance in this question the third party js library prefixtree was causing the problem by modifying the `<link>`, and there was an attribute that could be added to disable its effects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694456/google-fonts-giving-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the case, there are a few ways to fix this problem but I think these three are the most common solutions:

**1. [Google Cloud] Configuring CORS on a Bucket**

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://example
```

where *cors-json-file.json* is a your CORS configuration file:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://example.appspot.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

> **More:** https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

**2. [Nginx] Force Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Go to */etc/nginx/sites-available/[your_server_config]* and add this line into your server block:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

> **More:** https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx

**3. [Django-cors] Adds CORS headers to Django responses.**

Check this out:

- https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers
- [django-cors-headers not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046422/django-cors-headers-not-work/28834566)