# django-cors-headers not work

Tags: python, django, django-cors-headers

django-cors-headers not work

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'world',
    'userManager',
    'markPost',
    'BasicServices',
)


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Everything is normal, but did not work

here my response headers

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 13:16:17 GMT
Expires: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 13:16:17 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 13:16:17 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.8
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=snXksqpljbCLW0eZ0EElFxKbiUkYIvK0; expires=Tue, 19-Jan-2016 13:16:17 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: How u say CORS headers not working? Can u explain me?

Comment: Some 500 errors happen earlier than the CORS middleware, so it has no chance to add CORS headers. If the response status code was 500, this might be the issue and CORS might be working fine.

Answer (score 31):

I was having this same issue and everything seemed to be in the right place. Then I figured out that I had started the server before adding `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',` to the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. After making the correction, it was still not working. After trying a bunch of stuff, I opened it in another browser and it worked. So it turned out that I just needed to clear the browser cache.

Comment: Clearing the browser cache did it for me as well!

Comment: My god I just spent the last 1 bashing my head against the wall trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

According to the process_response code from [CorsMiddleware](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/blob/master/corsheaders/middleware.py):

```
response[ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN] = "*" if (
            settings.CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL and
            not settings.CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS) else origin
```

You must set settings like this:

```
# CORS Config
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

Comment: Where should I add this response ?

Answer (score 24):

Do not forget to add

> 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

at top of MIDDLEWARE variable :

See docs :

> CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before
>   any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's
>   CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise's WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not
>   before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these
>   responses.

Comment: This is SUPER important. I had some other middleware declared before corsmiddleware and it failed silently.

Answer (score 18):

Somehow `django-cors-headers` would not work for me with `Django 2` despite following all the steps. The pre-flight check would retrun a 405 error.

I ended up writing a small middleware:

```
from django import http


class CorsMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if (request.method == "OPTIONS"  and "HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD" in request.META):
            response = http.HttpResponse()
            response["Content-Length"] = "0"
            response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = 86400
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with"
        return response
```

Then added this middleware in my `settings.py` :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'apps.core.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
     ... others below it
]
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: django-cors-headers is trash. I just wanted to enable ACAO for all requests, spent an half of an hour to force it work, it started working locally but under basic auth in prod or due to another reason it does nothing, quietly nothing. Developers overcomplex it. 
On couponing this code I spend 1 minute, and it works perfectly everywhere.

Comment: This worked for me, and I followed [this middleware tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32242074/5671180)

Comment: django-cors-headers always had issues for me, but this did. Thank you!

Comment: Treid 10+ solutions related to django-cors-headers. None of them worked for a boilerplate I created from cookiecutter with a react frontend running separately. This is the only option that worked for me. To stop using django-cors-headers and use this custom middleware.

Comment: I spent an entire day, this solved it instantly.  There is some very obscure reason why django-cors-headers has issues.

Answer (score 12):

If you are testing this you need to ensure you include at least the Origin header in the request.

E.g.:

```
$ http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/todos/ Origin:http://www.someorigin.com
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 14 Nov 2015 04:42:38 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

You will get more feedback with a preflight CORS request:

```
$ http OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:8000/todos/ Origin:http://www.someorigin.com
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, content-type, accept, origin, authorization, x-csrftoken, user-agent, accept-encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 14 Nov 2015 04:45:37 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Answer (score 8):

I spent a couple of hours and tried a lot of solutions to fix this.
I think we need to followed the steps mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

One more step:
Finally it works after I added:

**CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']**

after:

ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

I think it allows all the headers including Authorization.

Answer (score 7):

I guess corsheaders and clickjacking middlewares are not compatible. At least I got rid off X-Frame-Options header when I commented out  `django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware`.

I've just `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` setting.

Comment: Yes! `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` Added to `settings.py ` it works perfectly for me, for my local development.

Answer (score 4):

I tried installing `django-cors-headers` to fix the error I was getting when running my django app with production settings.

> ' URL ' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image: CORS ERROR]

My app loads fine when running in development and installing `django-cors-headers` did not resolve the issue. For some reason chrome was blocking `Material` icons from loading when I was in production.

[image]

Once I discovered what the issue was I felt it was important to share how I fixed it as I feel a lot of people coming to this question will have the same circumstances.

### This solution will hopefully work for those who are serving their static content (like images) from another server such as an AWS S3 bucket like I was and getting this error.

If you are and it is being blocked by chrome in the same way, installing `django-cors-headers` won't do anything. This is because the problem lies with the configuration of the S3 bucket (Azure etc) and not the django app.

Go to the AWS S3 dashboard and once you select the bucket you are using to host the static files of your django app, click on the permissions tab.

[image: permissions tab of s3 bucket]

Scroll down to the `cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)` section and click 'Edit'.

[image: CORS section]

And if you want to just resolve the issue completely (for just serving static files blocked by chrome), enter the following JSON and then click 'Save changes' at the bottom.

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

There is more information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors) on how to configure your S3 bucket's CORS configuration.

After saving this configuration the error went away and my icons loaded properly.

[image: icons loading properly]

Footnote:

Given I was also misunderstanding how the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header worked I have taken an image from Mozilla's Doc's on [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) but edited it to show my situation to hopefully explain how the header works.

[image: server client diagram]

Imagine that Chrome and localhost were exchanging mail and all of a sudden chrome starts getting mail from AWS but it doesn't have Chromes name of it. Good guy Chrome is thinking, uh I don't know if I should be viewing this information, it isn't from the origin (localhost) so I don't know if I'm allowed and it could be sensitive information sent by mistake. Therefore I won't open it.

The Allow-Access-Control-Origin header is S3 writing on that mail 'it's ok, you (Chrome) have permission to view the information in this mail'.

`django-cors-headers` is necessary for situations were you have an app hosted on a server A (origin) that is making requests to a django app on server B, that is not the origin. For example, if your django app was a rest api hosted on heroku and you had a react/angular app hosted on Azure that made requests to that api - then your django app would need it.

[image: django app that needs django-cors-headers]

Answer (score 2):

From Django 2 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is changed to MIDDLEWARE. In this case if you have Django 2 make sure the MIDDLWARE is as it should be such that MIDDLEWARES get executed.

Answer (score 2):

I added 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' at the top of middleware array and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Final solution would be send response with CORS allowed headers.

```
response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
response['Content-Type'] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, OPTIONS"
response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, My-Token"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to add non-standard headers. Even if `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` is set, it will still check if the headers are allowed.

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
    'my-custom-header',  
]
```

The same can be done for non-standard methods:

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_methods

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = list(default_methods) + [
    'POKE',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
 CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
 CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ["*"]
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`
```

Answer (score 0):

**django-cors-headers** works perfectly for handling CORS policy issue.

After doing the above steps, just try to clear browser cache or try making same request in chrome(incognito) or firefox(private window).

Comment: Clearing the Browser cache worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the url inside an `iframe`?

If that is the case, then the header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` might be causing a problem.

To fix it remove the middleware, `django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware`.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the mentioned settings (After CORS installation and changing configs in `settings.py`) works, just turn off your adblocker if that is enabled for your local website. This small configuration worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**For those who have CORS error for FONTS**
For me the problem was solved by changing apache config.

add these lines of code to `VirtualHost` or `.htaccess`

for apache server, this file is in this directory:
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`
**important** if ssl certificate is enabled for your website, these codes should be added to ssl config file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was solved by CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to get a REACT app with Axios to connect to Django 4.1.1 with a routine set of API endpoints implemented with Django Rest Framework (DRF). The failure I was observing was that Django was NOT providing the "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response expected by Axios, during the preflight check for CORS.

There is a lot of chatter on Stackoverflow and elsewhere stating that this issue is caused by a failure to set proper headers with Axios, or that the simple steps to do basic setup of django-cors-headers would solve the issue (described at this link [django-cors-headers documentation]).

The most basic setup for django-cors-headers does not cause Django to respond properly to Axios during the preflight check. After setting:

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

in settings.py, Django correctly responded to the preflight check. This must be set in conjunction with the basic setup of django-cors-headers.

Note that my goal was simply to get a development environment working, not to deploy this in a production scenario. This works with the built in "server" for Django development (python3 manage.py runserver), using a React app also running as a development server with "npm start".

Of course for a production environment, the CORS settings above must be dialed in to ensure security, and I am not attempting to address that here. My only goal was to save other developers hours of searching, just to get a development environment up and running.

Also note that while Axios enforces CORS, "fetch" does not, and using a script that was auto generated by Postman would completely avoid the CORS issues. However, I wanted to use Axios, and was left no choice but to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if the **django-cors-headers** package has been installed properly and if the package and its dependencies have not been manipulated while doing something like `pip freeze` and `pip install`.Check if that might be the issue likewise me. In that scenario just do:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

make a fresh **requirements.txt** using

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Worked for me because I removed and updated multiple packages. So one of that actions misconfigured django-cors which caused CORS issues when the client tried to connect with the backend server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the response was not passing any `cors` hearders in pre-flight request. Hence I added the below and it worked.

In settings file add the below.

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ["*"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add something like this to settings.py

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS[
'https://YOUR-ADDRESS',
]

Answer (score -1):

What I did was depreciate the version of `django-cors-headers` for it to work.
I moved from version `3.2.1` to `2.4.0`. You can do that by installing the specific version using pip

```
pip install django-cors-headers==2.4.0
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case adding CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS fixed the problem.

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://website-url.com",
    "https://website-url.com",
]
```

It works without corsheaders too.

Answer (score -1):

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

All problem is solved. Using in Setting.py file.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```sh
python -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [  
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`
```

Make sure to include: `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware`, as high as possible

For reference: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/