# CORS error while consuming calling REST API with React

Tags: django, rest, reactjs, cors, django-rest-framework

I created a restful api with django-rest-framework accessible with this URL http://192.168.33.10:8002/scenarios/ and I'm creating a React app to make calls to the api an d consume its data.

I'm using fetch to make calls to the api

```
componentWillMount: function(){
 this.setState({Problemstyle: this.props.Problemstyle})
 fetch('http://192.168.33.10:8002/scenarios/')
 .then(result=>result.json())
 .then(result=> {
   this.steState({items:result})
 })
 },
```

when i run my app i get an error in my browser

> Fetch API cannot load http://192.168.33.10:8002/scenarios/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.33.10:8001' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I'm not sure on how to solve this problem as i'm just starting to use React

Comment: Your django-rest-framework app at http://192.168.33.10:8002/scenarios/ needs to be configured to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. Because it’s not currently returning that response header, your browser is not allowing your frontend JavaScript code to access the response. So you probably want to install https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/ on the http://192.168.33.10:8002/scenarios/ server

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Please Note: This solution is not for production configuration. This is merely a workaround for easier setup while development. Please refrain from using this in production configuration.**

Install django-cors-headers through `pip install django-cors-headers`

Then, add in installed apps 'corsheaders'.

Add the setting,

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

and,

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

This should do the trick.

**UPDATE**

You'll also need to add it to the middlewares,

```
MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Comment: This did the job yesterday. Today, when I am trying again, it's not working. Any suggestions

Comment: Is the error still the same?? Check your settings are being served properly and make sure nothing is overridden.

Comment: Do I need to do something at js also?? I am using axios.

Comment: Don't pass any custom headers for the request, other than that there's nothing to be bothered of.

Comment: did you add 'corsheaders' in installed_apps? Updated the answer

Comment: I believe that it is not neccesary add 'corsheaders' in installed_apps, my app working without add to installed_app

Comment: what if i have to send a custom header?

Comment: you should not just blindly use `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`, see the answer by tim-mccurrach

Comment: Please stop posting security broken solutions, its not even a solution, its a workaround of a very important security aspects. @zaidfazil I recommend you delete you answer or at least edit to say "Please this is only to show how NOT to do it"

Answer (score 25):

**The currently accepted answer potentially opens sites up to security risks:**

### Why does the error happen:

In order for your AJAX request to work well, there are two things that need to happen:

1. The request has to be accepted by the server.
2. The returned request must be accepted by the browser, so that the client-side can do something with it.

The error that the OP reports, indicates that the second part of this process is failing. This is because if the request is sent from domain that is different to the server returning the request, the browser won't accept it unless the appropriate headers are set (that is, the **server** has given permission for the browser to read it).

### How to fix it:

Now to fix this, we can use `django-cors-headers`. This will add the apropriate headers, so that the browser accepts the returned response. To install run:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

and add it to your middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Now, you need to add the domain you are sending your AJAX request from, to the list of allowed domains:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "www.example.com",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    ...
]
```

### What about `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL`?

Do not use this unless you have a specific need to. Setting this to true, will mean that, any origin will be able to make a request to your API, and get a response. Unless you are making a public API, you probably won't need to do this. More likely you will only need to serve a single domain or a few domains (maybe you have a front-end, served from a different place to your API etc.)

If you **are** happy for any domain to access your API then you can set the following:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

If you do this, you will also need to set the following:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

The reason for this, is Django will only accept certain hosts by default, so there's no point setting `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` unless you're actually going to accept requests from anyone (that is the part 1 in the explanation above).

Note that by setting allowed hosts to a wildcard, you open yourself up to HTTP host header attacks. Make sure you understand these, and have made sure you are not affected. You can read more about them [in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/security/#host-headers-virtual-hosting).

Also note: if you have not set your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and you are wondering why your requests are working, it is because when `DEBUG=True` certain hosts are allowed automatically, `http://127.0.0.1:8000` etc.

Comment: So if our project includes a public API we can set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mydomain.com']`, right? Given that public API is on a subdomain like `api.mydomain.com`.

Comment: This is also very relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/48116156/7088936

Comment: I have done this but still  sometimes  we  get CORS error and now i dont know what to do

Answer (score 4):

Using django-cors-headers

Start by installing django-cors-headers using pip

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

You need to add it to your project settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ##...
    'corsheaders'
)
```

Next you need to add corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware middleware to the middleware classes in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #...
)
```

You can then, either enable CORS for all domains by adding the following setting

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Or Only enable CORS for specified domains:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http//:localhost:8000',
)
```

Comment: Amazing! The other answers are missing the fact that you need to add `corseheaders` into the `INSTALLED_APPS` block.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE (12.12.22)

Just add to the `package.json` file the following line:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

### OLD ANSWER

Based on [Joe Sadoski's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705296/joe-sadoski) great idea,

I suggest an improvement to his solution that also supports react hot-reload-on-changes:

(All other proposed solutions here do not work in chrome since the last upgrades in **2022**)

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
    volumes: 
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    environment:
    - NGINX_HOST=localhost
    - NGINX_PORT=80
    network_mode: host
    restart: unless-stopped
```

My change here is: `network_mode: host`

Now the `nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
events {}
http{
    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name localhost;
        
        // this block handle react hot-reload
        location /sockjs-node {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        // this block handle API calls
        location ~* /(accounts|api|admin)  {
            proxy_pass   http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }


        // this block handle all the rest (react/statics...)
        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I change the upstreams to point on `localhost` so both react server and django should run on the host computer in ports `3000` and `8000`.

So, after `docker-compose up`, `manage.py runserver`, and `npm start`, both apps are available at `http://localhost`!

Comment: The updated answer will work only if you are using Create react app.

Answer (score 1):

See [Yinon_90's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72004611/705296) for a better working version of this concept.

---

I wanted to propose a solution that does not require altering the behavior of the Django or React apps.

In production, you might want to serve both apps on the same domain/from the same server, under different paths. This wouldn't cause any CORS conflict in production.

Of course, we want to debug Django and utilize React HMR & Dev tools while debugging. For this, I've spun up an nginx docker container:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
    volumes: 
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    environment:
    - NGINX_HOST=localhost
    - NGINX_PORT=80
```

`nginx.conf`:

Django debug is on port 8000, React HMR is on port 3000. I've allowed three paths to go to the Django app, `/accounts`, `/api`, and `/admin`. The rest goes to the React app (and into the React Router system)

```
events {}
http{
    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name localhost;
        location ~* /(accounts|api|admin) {
            proxy_pass      http://host.docker.internal:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass      http://host.docker.internal:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

After `docker-compose up`, `manage.py runserver`, and `npm start`, both apps are available at `localhost:8000`!

Comment: Nice solution, but in this way, you lose the fun of react's hot-reload, you must refresh the browser to see the frontend's changes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, It was quite funny I was getting 200 code and swagger was working correctly, but react didn't work properly.
simply these require in the setting.py:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

and for front:

```
const setCookie = async () => {
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/core/csrf-cookie/`, {
                headers: { 'Authorization': null },
                withCredentials: true,
            }
        ).catch( () => {
            console.log('Something went wrong!')
        });
        setCsrfToken(getCookie('csrftoken'))
        console.log(csrfToken)
    }
```

call setCookie in the useEffect and it should work.

and Don't forget to build react and set `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`should never be used in production. For local its fine.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a solution for those who have set everything as required by `django-cors-headers` but are still getting an error such as:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Well, the problem, at least in my case, was that `django-cors-headers` did not recognize `http://localhost:5173` for some reason. As we know localhost has the IP address `127.0.0.1`. So I changed the host address of my react server to explicitly use the IP address `127.0.0.1`. I was using react with vite so I did the following changes in my `vite.confing.ts` to set a new domain:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  server: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',  // Set the host to 127.0.0.1
    port: 5173,         // Set the port to 5173
  },
})
```

So the domain of my frontend server after that will be `http://127.0.0.1:5173`.

Now you only have to add this new domain to `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` in `settings.py` and the error should be resolved.

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
     'http://127.0.0.1:5173',
]
```

##### --- End of solution ---

Further information for context:

- OS: Windows 11
- API calls made using: **axios**.
- If you want to see the difference of `http://localhost:5173` and `http://127.0.0.1:5173` try starting your frontend server using each of them and each time check how the system represents these domains behind the scene using the cmd command `netstat -ano`.