# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Django and React

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

[image: Cross Origin Request Blocked]

I have installed `pip install django-cors-headers` still not working

added into the settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

[image]

[image]

Django Rest Framework

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037474/cors-error-while-consuming-calling-rest-api-with-react?

Comment: nope its not working .. I tried everything source code: https://github.com/avichhetri8/djangowithreact  branch dev

Comment: try adding `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` as first item i the `MIDDLEWARES` list

Comment: yes it is above `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` please check the source code https://github.com/avichhetri8/djangowithreact/blob/dev/ecom/settings.py

Comment: Try `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True`

Comment: Are you behind nginx or such ?

Comment: Nope i have not used any of those .... please check my source code https://github.com/avichhetri8/djangowithreact/tree/dev

Comment: Its not working after adding CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True inside settings.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had same issue in project solution that i got is

1. Place corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware at the top

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
   'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   ..........
   ..........
   ]
   ```
2. ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
3. Add at the bottom of the settings.py

   ```
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
   ```

According to [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)
CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses.

Also if you are using CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER it should be placed before Django’s CsrfViewMiddleware (see more below).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, for such error you need to update `settings.py` with `django-cors-headers`:

```py
# update backend/server/server/settings.py
# ...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'corsheaders', # add it here
    #...
]

# define which origins are allowed
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
]

# add to middleware
MIDDLEWARE = [
    #...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #...
]
```

Sometimes you also need to set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=["127.0.0.1"]` or with your other address (you can also try with "*", but just for debug).

You can check details in my article: [React Token Based Authentication to Django REST API Backend](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-token-based-authentication-django/).

Please also try to run tests with a cleared cache in the web browser.

If that doesn't help please provide more details about your project setup.

Comment: please check my source source its not working https://github.com/avichhetri8/djangowithreact/blob/dev/ecom/settings.py