# Django REST Framework -- ALLOWED_HOSTS setting for a public open API -- What to enter?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, hosting, rest

I know this seems like a duplicate but this actually was intended to be a comment under an answer but I cannot comment with my current reputation score.

I'm new when it comes to Django and REST-APIs. I am developing an open API that is publicly accessible.

While researching about the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting in Django, I stumbled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458772/16172996) answer. The author suggests to set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to `True` and says that if you do that, you also want to set a wildcard for the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

I understand that for an open API, I want to set CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL to True but I don't understand why I would want to set a wildcard for ALLOWED_HOSTS. From my understanding, you want to set only the hostname of the server(s) the API is running on, correct?

I read the django documentation and some other sources but I feel like I don't understand this enough yet.

Could you elaborate @tim-mccurrach? I unfortunately cannot comment under your answer in the original question because I don't have the 50 point reputation score yet.

Comment: You understand it correctly. `ALLOWED_HOSTS` should be set to only host names which we allow to be served. For example, in production should be a production domain (or production server IP if you want to).