# ReactJS + django 400 bad request

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm making website using django and react. I have already set up backend in django and [tested it using postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wAk9.png), everything works fine but when I'm doing exact same thing using react i'm getting 400 error.

Tried to do it like that:

To avoid any other error I used static data in this example

```
export default function MakePost(){
    
    
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState(1);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    
    const submit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
            
        
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({id: 1, text: 'some text'})
        }
        
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/make-post/', requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            if(response.ok){
                return response.json();
            }
            
        });
        
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: This is probably a CORS issue. Add a catch() method to the fetch Promise chain and console.log the error to get more details. This might be relevant to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037474/cors-error-while-consuming-calling-rest-api-with-react