# How to solve CORS problem of my Django API?

Tags: python, django, docker, cors

I cannot solve CORS problem in my Django API. When I make a call to this API, I get error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/' from origin
>   'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

To enable CORS, I did `pip install django-cors-headers` and added the following code to `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'localhost:80',
    'localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1:8000'
]
```

I should say that I run my project on Docker. This is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  django-docker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.django
    container_name: my.django
    image: my-django
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  webapp-docker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.webapp
    container_name: my.webapp
    image: my-web
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` middleware to the middleware classes in `settings.py` :

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #...
)
```

You have duplicate `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` in your middleware classes.

You can then, either enable CORS for all domains by adding the following setting:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Or Only enable CORS for specified domains:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:8000',
)
```

Comment: Damn u, ':' is after http and not just before localhost. spent an hour figuring that out :D. +1

Comment: I just spent a week debugging a nasty CORS issue. Notice that you cannot allow all when you have authorization. Also - the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES are nowadays called MIDDLEWARE.

Comment: If you've got rare case of API without any authentication you may also need to set `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28834566/1927853)

Answer (score 9):

Try to add this in your settings:

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
)
```

Comment: If you want to resolve quickly this issue add: CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True. However, this is not a recommended production settings. Have you tried to set the name of your container in the CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST  ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I visited `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in my browser but used `fetch('http://localhost:8000');` in my JavaScript code. The solution is to use either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` but not mix them.

Comment: That doesn't work because when you are using different ports it gets treated as a different domain.

Comment: @Spartacus In my case, the port was the same but I was using a different domain (even though they typically mean the same thing). If the ports differ then, you are correct, this won't solve the problem. Even with different ports, it is advisable to consitently use either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` but not mix and match them.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me, was installing **django-cors-headers**:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Then update the django settings.py file with the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "corsheaders",
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another tip that I haven't seen mentioned anywhere.

When testing your Django app from a HTML file that you have stored locally and opened up from your file system, the submit form will have a Null origin.

Therefore to let CORS permit this you need to add Null to your CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS settings such as:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "null",
]
```

**HOWEVER** allowing requests from a null origin can introduce potential security concerns, as it opens up your Django application to requests from any source, including local file systems and potentially malicious origins.

What I should have been doing is placing my test.html into the djagno folder and accessing it via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.html` instead.