# django-cors-headers and nginx config: preflight response missing CORS headers

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, cors, django-cors-headers

I use django-cors-headers 3.1.1 for handling the requests and responses between my Django-backend and Javascript-frontend apps. Transport is non-secured (i.e. http, not https).

When hosted locally, everything works fine. But after deploying on the server, I stopped seeing the CORS headers.

Here are headers in development:
[image]
and in production:
[image]

Error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://[HOST_IP]/api/assets/' from origin 'http://my_custom_domain.eu' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My nginx configurations looks as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name [HOST_IP];

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/[path_to_app]/app.sock;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'PUT') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/[path_to_app]/site/static/;
    }
}
```

The django-cors-headers’ settings are now identical in development and in production:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    …
    "corsheaders",
    …
)
MIDDLEWARE = [
    …
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    …
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ['DELETE','GET','OPTIONS','PATCH','POST','PUT']
```

On the client side I tried to add ‘'Access-Control-Request-Method’: ‘PUT’ header, but this was refused by the browser. There’s noting unusual in the client call:

```
  axios({
    method: 'put',
    url: `${this.backendUrl}/api/assets/`,
    data: formData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    }
  })
```

Also, I’m trying to host on the Amazon AWS EC2 for the first time, so perhaps there is some required AWS configuration I am not aware of. For example, is it necessary to enable CORS using the API Gateway? The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/enable-cors-for-resource-using-swagger-importer-tool.html) does not say so (‘If you are using the API Gateway Import API, you can set up CORS support using an OpenAPI file’).

The frontend application is hosted on a S3 bucket with the following CORS policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

What am I missing here? Is there some needed server-side (nginx especially) configuration?

Some other solutions I’ve tried:

I have doubts, whether the request/response origin is correct (e.g. APPEND_SLASH variable). But if this is the case, shouldn’t an error be raised when hosted locally?

I also tried setting proxy headers as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371815/cors-issue-with-django-and-react-hosted-on-same-server), but without knowing nginx very well this was doomed to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by changing 3 things:

### AWS

I noticed that [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/cors-support.html) states:

> CORS is already enabled for the Amazon EC2 API, and is ready for you
>   to use. You do not need to perform any additional configuration steps
>   to start using this feature. There is no change to the way that you
>   make calls to the Amazon EC2 API; they must still be signed with valid
>   AWS credentials to ensure that AWS can authenticate the requestor. […]

This is usually handled by AWS SDK or CLI, but in my case I used none of them, so I had to add `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. In my case I simply used [aws4 library](https://github.com/mhart/aws4):

```
  axios(aws4.sign({
    accessKeyId: this.awsAccessKey,
    secretAccessKey: this.awsSecretAccessKey,
    method: 'put',
    url: `${this.backendUrl}/api/assets/`,
    data: formData,
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    service: 'ec2',
    region: 'eu-central-1',
    path: '/',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
  }))
```

I’ve seen plenty of examples how to add AWS Signature v.4 without any additional dependency, though.

### NGINX

In nginx configuration I placed all add_headers statements into conditional code-blocks. Idea came from [this post](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name [HOST_IP];

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/[path_to_app]/app.sock;


        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,X-Amz-Date';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'PUT') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,X-Amz-Date';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,X-Amz-Date';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/analizy/be/site/static/;
    }
}
```

### Django-cors-header

Here it sufficed to add non-default headers.

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
    'X-Amz-Date',
]
```

---

Hope that this will help someone.