# Not able to make a GET request to the django REST API backend for the id=1 article, from axios in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, react-hooks

I have a frontend application built using reactjs and django rest framework is used to serve this frontend using APIs. The django rest APIs are working fine, I have checked via Postman.

When I make a GET request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/`, I get the list of articles, and when I click on one of them, it is supposed to take me to the `article detail page` for that specific id of the article. This is done by making a GET request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/id`.

The problem is, when I make GET request for id=2,3,4,5,... , it works fine. But when I try to make a request for id=1, I get the following error at console of chrome browser

```js
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

So, the request is not made at all(I verified from server side). All I get is the above error.
**Please note that there is no such error for `articles/2` or `articles/3` and so on. I have allowed the relevant host in django `settings.py` file.**

This is the code I have for the `article detail page`.

```js
function ArticlePage(props) {
    const [MainArticle, setMainArticle] = useState({});
    const {id} = useParams()
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/'+id;
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("hello world");
        axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                setMainArticle(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error)=>console.log(error))
    }, [url]);
    return (
        <section className="postsBody">
            <Article 
                title={MainArticle.title}
                author={MainArticle.author}
                timestamp={MainArticle.timestamp}
                content={MainArticle.content}
            />
        </section>
    )
}
```

Please help me out with this error, via debugging I came to know that the problem is not in the server side, the GET request works for id=1 via postman.

Comment: Please add the response of the request with `id = 1`.

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar I have updated the question. The request is not made at all for id=1. I get the error as specified above. This error is the same as what I would have got, if I would not have allowed the localhost in ALLOWED HOSTS of django, which is not the case.

Comment: Maybe there is a route conflict on your server-side. And, I don't know about django.

Comment: If that is the case, then why do I get correct json data via postman

Comment: This is really strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem eventually. The problem is the browser cache. I updated django, djago-rest-framework, react and react-router-dom. Then I did a `hard reload` of the localhost:3000 website and it eventually started working. The key point is to clear the browser cache just after you add `corsheaders` and it will work. I took help from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046422/django-cors-headers-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the CORS policy. Even if you allow the sites in the settings, you need to explicitly enable those websites to access content from your backend. Install [cors headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) app in Django and set the allowed origins. The documentation for `cors headers` has sufficient information.

Comment: I have mentioned `corsheaders` in the installed apps and also added the required middlewares as mentioned in the documentation. Listed "http://localhost:3000" in the CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS, still it doesn't work. I mean it of course works for other id values than 1. Please help me out.
I am getting the same `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error for some reason.

Comment: I found that the problem was browse cache and wrote a new answer.