# CORS for Django rest framework

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, cors

*EDIT: I found a solution, but I still don't understand the issue. For the second viewset, the CORS worked fine and if I changed the URL of the users viewset to anything else (e.g. '/user' instead of '/users') it also worked fine. So for some reason the '/users' URL seems to be some kind of special reserved URL that does not go through the CORS middleware? I was just very unlucky with the example that I picked. Can someone explain why this is and if there are other such reserved URL names?*

I'm planning to make an app with Vue.js in the frontend and Django rest framework in the backend, so I was playing around with a small test app, but I can't figure out the correct CORS settings. I see many people online having issues with this, but none of the solutions seems to work for me.

Below you can find the code of the files that might be relevant. I tried everything mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046422/django-cors-headers-not-work) and [this](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/vue-cors-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/) article and many more. Things that I tried are: add corsheaders to installed apps, add the middleware (at the top of the middleware list, as suggested in the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)), set CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS to True, set CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS, set ALLOWED_HOSTS and CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS to ['*'], set the proxy in the vue.config file and using a different browser/clearing browser cache.

I believe the problem is in the backend, and the frontend is configured OK, but to be sure I'm also including the frontend files. Calling the view directly in the browser works fine (it does not use any authentication). The error that I get in the console is

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/users' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Here is the settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-fm#w5*v$mjwo4gshdddank7==_ul5pki5tmngx-yy7bqm6#juh'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
#     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8080',
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Here is the vue file from which the request is sent (whenever the text bla bla is clicked):

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ testResult }}
    </div>
    <div @click="dummyGet">
        bla bla {{ id }}: {{ number }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ firstName }} has age {{ age }} {{ age > 25 ? ' and is old' : ''}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000';
    export default {
        name:'TestA',
        data() {
            return{
                testResult: null
            }
        },
        props: [
            'firstName', 'age'
        ],
        methods: {
            async dummyGet() {
                this.testResult = await axios.get('/users')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the vue.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:8000'
  }
})
```

And here is the view that is invoked (UserViewSet). This view does not need authentication.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from test_api.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = []#permissions.IsAuthenticated]


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

Here's a pip freeze (I'm using python 3.10.13):

```
asgiref==3.7.2
asttokens==2.2.1
backcall==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.6
comm==0.1.2
debugpy==1.6.6
decorator==5.1.1
Django==4.2.5
django-cors-headers==4.2.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
executing==1.2.0
ipykernel==6.21.2
ipython==8.11.0
jedi==0.18.2
jupyter_client==8.0.3
jupyter_core==5.2.0
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
parso==0.8.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
prompt-toolkit==3.0.38
psutil==5.9.4
pure-eval==0.2.2
Pygments==2.14.0
pytz==2023.3.post1
pywin32==305
pyzmq==25.0.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
stack-data==0.6.2
tornado==6.2
traitlets==5.9.0
typing_extensions==4.7.1
tzdata==2023.3
wcwidth==0.2.6
```

Comment: I want to point to a nuance of the request error you are getting. The CORS headers are missing, and sometimes this error is returned when the request does not reach the django backed (which provides those headers). I've encountered this situation when using nginx as a reverse proxy or gunicorn with a faulty configuration. So one of the thing you should check is if the request is indeed reaching django cors midleware