# Blocked web-fonts from localhost in different ports

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain, access-control, google-webfonts

I want to fix an error, it's this:

> Font from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

All my assets are located en **localhost:8000** and my public website is located in **localhost:3000**, beacuse my assets are located en a directory outside root directory of the public web.

The both directories have an **.htaccess** file.

Any idea to fix this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As metioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694456/google-fonts-giving-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r), I fixed this issue by adding `data-noprefix` to the link tag for my stylesheet.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/yourFont" rel="stylesheet" data-noprefix>
```